# ¿Como puedo llegar al final del right de un arbol?

Tags: javascript, árboles-binarios

mi pregunta es esa, estoy realizando un ejercicio sobre arboles binarios en js y me pide devolver los dos valores maximos y retornarlos en un array. Como ya se sabe que los valores mas grandes al root van a la derecha y asi con cada valor consecutivo en direccion right pense en ir hasta que el valor que le sigue al right del right sea null asi parandome en el anteultimo valor en direccion right. Por si no me explique de forma correcta creo que con un ejemplo se entenderia mejor:
[image]

Por ejemplo si este fuera el arbol me gustaria pararme en el 33 y pushear a un array el 33 y el 45
cuestion que a la hora de pasar esto a codigo me cuesta un monton, no se como hacerlo. Si alguno me ayuda con algo se lo agradeceria

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código

Comment: ¡Hola! Bienvenido(a) a SOes. Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Qué haz intentado? donde está el error? edita tu pregunta y agrega tu código con su respectivo formato.